# use cmake add_definition value in fortran

Tags: cmake, fortran, precompiler

I'd like to include a flag such as `-DMY_FLAG=ONETWOTHREE` in the CMake call, i.e. `make .. -DMY_FLAG=ONETWOTHREE`, and get the value of `MY_FLAG` in the fortran code. I'm using `add_definitions("-DMY_FLAG=${MY_FLAG}")` to pass `MY_FLAG` to `make`.

Currently, when I do something like
`write(*,*) MY_FLAG`

I get this compiler error:
`Error: Symbol 'ONETWOTHREE' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type`

Can the `-D` flags be cast to a type in fortran? It looks like `MY_FLAG` is somehow defined at compile time, but it has no type.

Comment: What fortran compiler?

Comment: At the moment, gfortran 7.1

Comment: Then this is a problem with the source code, which is what the below answer seems to say also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a preprocessor, the final source file must be valid Fortran. In the present situation,

```
write(*,*) ONETWOTHREE
```

is not valid because there is not variable named `ONETWOTHREE`.

Solutions:

1. Define the variable earlier:

   ```
   integer ONETWOTHREE
   ONETWOTHREE = 5
   ```
2. Do not use `ONETWOTHREE` but an actual value. Example for an integer:

   ```
   -DMY_FLAG=123
   ```

   so that the corresponding line will be

   ```
   write(*,*) 123
   ```

Of course, it would be useful if you could provide us with the intention behind the usage of the preprocessor here.

Comment: apparently cmake wants a specific syntax when using `add_definitions`. does NOT work: `add_definitions("-DMY_FLAG=${MY_FLAG}")`. does work: `add_definitions(-DMY_FLAG="${MY_FLAG}")`. This is for a string value for `MY_FLAG`. For a numeric value, no quotes are necessary.

Comment: This is in line with the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_definitions.html): overall quoting inside `add_definitions` is not to be used. The quotes are for the replacement in the source code as strings are quoted in Fortran.